# How to create drop down column OR filters

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet (in Excel 2003) that has a number of cross-reference cells, for example:

```
1   Red|Green|Blue|Yellow|Any|Information
2    X |     |    |      |   |....
3    X |     |    |      | X |....
4      |     | X  |      | X |....
5      |     | X  |      |   |....
5      |     | X  |  X   |   |....
```

Now, the stock autofilter allows me to insert dropdown selectors so I can filter the rows based on the presence of an X in any given column. 
eg I can filter on all rows tagged (with an X) as Red

However, what I want to be able to do, via a simple dropdown menu, is to be able to filter the rows based on two columns, OR-ed together (not AND-ed)

eg Using the stock autofilter, if I selected 'X' in column 'Red', and 'X' in column 'Any', I would get 1 row displayed (row 3) for the only record with Red AND Any checked.

I want it to display all the rows that have an 'X' in column 'Red' OR an 'X' in column 'Any' (ie rows 1 to 3)

Is this possible without VBA?

I'm aware that the Advance Filter can provide similar functionality (albeit in a manual process), but that does not provide a simple drop-down style interface to toggle it, which I need for basic users of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you use an advanced or custom sort?

Comment: As I mentioned, whilst the advanced sort does provide similar functionality, it doesn't give the simple drop down selector to apply it.

Comment: Well, I didn't see you mention sort. Autofilters are different than sorts, technically, in excel. If you meant both, then I apologize. The only thing I can think of is to create a macro for a multi-level sort and place a button to run it.

Comment: If you can add a new column to the worksheet, the formula `=OR($A2="X",$E2="X")` can serve as the simple toggle filter.

Answer (score 0):

---

### Dropdown with helper column

You can use the formula `=OR(B:B="x",F:F="x")` in column `G` and autofilter on that:
[image]

Filtered on `TRUE`:

[image]

---

#### I don't know how to make this a drop-down without VBA, but here are the instructions just in case

All right, you can do an `or` but it will also include the `and` naturally, as the `and` meets **both** `or` criteria -

**note**: This is for numerical data and uses numerical operators, but it's the only way I know how. Maybe you can modify it for `=x`

Say you have your table in `A1:F7` like this, you **must define your criteria in another table in different rows**. I used `B9:F10`. Like this:
[image]

Note that my filters have the same titles as my data `colors`. Now, I go to **Advanced Filter** and put in my table and criteria like this:
[image]

Now, when I filter, I get the `or` results:
[image]

Sorry, I misread your question yesterday, otherwise I would have posted this sooner.